# ajax not working for getting url value stored in a constant

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hello everyone i am beginner in js/ajax and php so sorry in advance if u feel my question is a childish one i am have define the site url in my config file

config.inc.php

$config['siteurl']= "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/abc";

define('siteurl', $config['siteurl']);

now on my page em including the config file and i checked i am greeting the url value but what i want is to print the value in window.location.heref="" here my function

```js
$('#form_id').submit(function (e){
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($this.attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function (responseData) {
   if(responseData == "success"){
    window.location.href =  <?php echo (siteurl) ?>;
   } 
   else if (responseData){
     swal({
         title: "Error!",
          text: responseData,
          type: "error",
          confirmButtonText: "ok"
          });
   }
      
    

    });
});
```

if i use  window.location.href= " http://localhost/abc/abc.php"; it works fine

Comment: this `"/abc"` and this `/abc.php"` ... check the diff ***AND*** site url is `window.location.href =  <?php echo (siteurl) ?>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"'"+<?php echo (siteurl) ?>+"'"
```

use this may this work properly

Comment: because by syntax this is --- window.location.href = " <link>" --- compiler needs to read this completely and take link as string.

Comment: well still em not digesting this thing but my problem solved thanks for that bro

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
window.location.href =  <?php echo (siteurl) ?>;
```

To

```
window.location.href =  "<?php echo (siteurl) ?>";
```

You need to wrap the output of the constant in quotes for JS to pick it up as a string (which it requires for a URI)

Comment: plus i forget to put here